# Is there a difference between those ways to store an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I guess all the solutions below are equivalent (part from 4) but is it only a matter of preference?

```
Object* myArray[10];                             // 1. C-style
std::array<Object*, 10> myArray;                 // 2. C++11
boost::ptr_array<Object, 10>myArray;             // 3. Boost
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Object>, 10> myArray; // 4. taking ownership of the pointer
```

Why isn't there a class in Boost doing what line 4 is doing in a `ptr_array`-like way? Is it because generally there isn't a good reason to store an array of pointers if the class containing it is taking ownership and destroys the objects when necessary?

The alternative that I can see to line 4 would be to have an array of objects instead of pointers of objects: `std::array<Object, 10> myArray`.

**Edit:** Removed the "best-way" thing in the question as it wasn't really relevant.

Comment: Depending on use, you can use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: The "best way" will depend on why you want an array of pointers and what you plan to do with it.

Comment: There is no "best way". It really depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming there is no such thing as "best way" that is independent of goals.

All the variants have their pros&cons, and you evaluate them against what you want to do. Drop the hopeless ones and pick some of the remaining.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't correctly written... Is there a difference between 1, 2 and 3 then? Any reason to prefer one instead of the other? And why isn't there a smart_ptr_array in Boost that would take ownership of the pointers?

Comment: You can post another question with that ;-)  Of course there is a difference between the first three, and you can use boost::array<boost::shared_ptr<T>>> for the latter task, so there's little motivation to add yet another alternative

Comment: Well, as far as I understand there is no difference between `boost::ptr_array<T, size>` and `boost::array<T*, size>`. I found ptr_array recently, didn't know it existed before. That's why I'm even wondering why it's there. If there is little motivation to add alternative ways of doing things, what is the purpose of `Boost.ptr_container`? (this is a genuine question, not a basic troll-feeding attempt)

Comment: "there is no difference between boost::ptr_array<T, size> and boost::array<T*, size>"  Come again?

Comment: Is there any difference between those two?

Comment: boost is a coalition of independent libs and each has its ofn life cycle, some overlap may be created by some functionality missing at some time point and covered in separate lib -- that is then kept for back compatibility.  I guess ptr_container became obsolete with C++11 that allowed collecting `unique_ptr`-s

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense now. It explains why there are `auto_ptr` everywhere in that library... Thanks for the help understanding that!

Comment: @Uflex There's actually almost no similarity between `boost::ptr_array<T, size>` and `boost::array<T*, size>`.  The interface of the first is in terms of `T`, not `T*`; const-ness propagates to the actual objects, and not just the pointers; and it will delete the objects when the corresponding element is overwritten, or in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that if your pointers are pointing to memory allocated in heap (and this is very important) and are going to be deleted later you shouldn't use first 2 options in modern C++ as it is not safe in case of thrown exceptions.

Use RAII principle as often as you can so in general you should prefer 3rd and 4th option. Both 3rd and 4th option do not make *any* overhead (except of increased compile-time as they do use templates) so you don't have any major disadvantages.